# How to prevent memory leak of subscriptions creation when perform an event?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-cli

I need to make sure there is a single subscription (e.g. within the constructor) and chain the flow of events from another component to an observable property of this component.

The code I wrote does not prevent the memory-leak and creates a new subscription at each event.

*Image component ts*

```
export class ImagePanelComponent{
   constructor(
    private servicee: service,
    private status: status,
  ) {
  }

  updatePage(viewerPage: number){
    this.service.pages$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      (pages) => this.status.updatePage$.next(pages[viewerPage - 1]),
    );
  }
}
```

*Image component HTML*

```
<x-panel>
  <div content>
        <osd-component
            *ngIf="viewerData"
            [viewerData]="viewerData"
            [page]="pageNumber"
            (pageChange)="updatePage($event)">
        </osd-component>
        <p *ngIf="!viewerData">Found no source file</p>
  </div>
</x-panel>
```

Comment: You'll need an intermediate Subject and then on each `updatePage` even you call `Subject.next()`

Comment: actually I would say there is now Memory leak here, as the Subscription is destroyed after the first emit because of `take(1)`

Comment: @martin can you please give me an example? i understand what you mean but unfortunately i don't know how to implement it. Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @TobiasS. there is a memory leak beacuse each time `pageChange` emits a new subscription is created. That subscription will be completed after one emission (to your point) but the code does create multiple subscriptions as it's currently written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `BehaviorSubect` to keep track of the `pageChange` event emissions should work for this.

Something like:

```
export class ImagePanelComponent{
   constructor(
    private servicee: service,
    private status: status,
  ) {
     this._setSubscriptions();
  }

  private pages$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  updatePage(viewerPage: number){
    this.pages$.next(viewerPage);
  }
  
  _setSubscriptions() {
    // Here is your subscription to pages$ where you'll call your service to update the page number.
    // Note: You'll need to handle your unsubscribe logic (this.unsubscribe) 
    this.pages$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(
      (page) => this.service.SomeUpdatePageMethod(pages[page - 1])
    );
  }

}
```